# Redis combination of key attributes

Tags: redis

I am trying to build an analytics system where we need counters for number of records sent from a product. The records will have product name, version, platform on which it is running and other relevant information.

Later on we will need to create reports based on various combinations like only by product, specific product/version, specific product/platform, only by platform and so on and so forth.

So having redis keys like below I assume is ugly, because we have to increment all combinations of keys

```
prod:ABC:ver:v1:plat:macos:record //all attributes, name, version ,platform
prod:ABC:record                   //only product name
prod:ABC:ver:v2:record            //name and version
...
```

Is there any better way to deal with this problem?

I am pretty new to Redis

Answer (score 0):

what you can do :

for each possible records info, maintain a dedicated redis set

> "platform:fedora" "product:toto" "product:toto:v2" ...

when you create a new record, save it in a specific key, with a unique id

> "records:323456"

push this id into all the matching set for this record,

> "SADD platform:fedora 323456"

after, use [redis sinter command](http://redis.io/commands/sinter) to made intersection between your sets, depending on your query

> "SINTER platform:fedora product:toto"

to catch all users of toto onto fedora